# Measure time for external API call: handle asynchronism in angular

Tags: angular, asynchronous

I just need a simple angular application to call an external API (get request) and measure how long the application need to get the data.

My code looked like this:

```
  measureData(): {
    this.t0 = performance.now();

    this.errors = '';

    this.getHello().subscribe(
      (result: string) =>
        {
          this.text = result
          console.log("test")
          return this.text
        },
        error => {
          this.errors = error.message
          console.log(error.message)
          return this.errors
        }
    )
    this.t1 = performance.now();
    this.test = this.t1 - this.t0;
    console.log("Action took " + this.test + " milliseconds.")
    this.times.push(this.test);
  }
```

In this case I am in trouble with asynchronism. So I tried this:

```
main(){
    this.measureData().subscribe(
      (result: String) => {
        this.measurePerformance();
      }
    )
  }

  measureData(): Observable<any> {
    this.t0 = performance.now();

    this.errors = '';

    this.getHello().subscribe(
      (result: string) =>
        {
          this.text = result
          console.log("test")
          return this.text
        },
        error => {
          this.errors = error.message
          console.log(error.message)
          return this.errors
        }
    )
    return 
  }  

  measurePerformance() {
    this.t1 = performance.now();
    this.test = this.t1 - this.t0;
    console.log("Action took " + this.test + " milliseconds.")
    this.times.push(this.test);
  }
```

In this case I am getting this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You can measure the time elapsed with the following:

```
var start = new Date().getTime();
```

`// Your code`

```
var end = new Date().getTime();

var elapsedTime = end -start;

console.log("Time", elapsedTime );
```

Comment: same problem. Measuring time will be finished before I get back the data from getHello()

Comment: Try to await before  this.getHello() and async  measureData():

Answer (score 0):

For my solution I used `await delay(500)`.

```
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
```

My full code:

```
async measureData() {

   this.errors = '';
   const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

   for (let i = 0; i < this.numberMeasurements; i++) {
     this.t0 = performance.now();
     this.getHello().subscribe(
       (result: string) => {
         this.text = result
         this.t1 = performance.now();
         this.test = this.t1 - this.t0;
         console.log("Action took " + this.test + " milliseconds.")
         this.times.push(this.test);
         console.log(result)
       },
       error => {
         this.errors = error.message
         console.log(error.message)
       }
     )
     await delay(500);
   }

 }
```